# How to create x groups of y numbers, groups are not to overlap each other from a set range of numbers ie.. 1-80

Tags: delphi, math

I am trying to figure out a good method on how to create a number of groups, that contain so many numbers from a set range of numbers.

So in better explaining:-

`x = number of groups to be created. y = the total amount of numbers to each group created. z = the range of numbers from 1-80 to pick from - Matrix of 8 rows, 10 Columns.` 
The groups themselves should be in a block style i.e. 19,29,20,30 (2x2) block and no group is to overlap any other group as well.

For any examples to this question, please use for now x=2 and y=4 and z=80 (0 is invalid)

How would I code this or by using a math formula to get this done?

I am trying to do this in a Delphi application that I am creating for myself.

I really appreciate any insight on this question.  Thank you.

Logical programming, but gets too messy, there has to be an efficient formula for this kind of problem.

Comment: There is no magic formula... You have to elaborate approach - how to choose blocks. For example - can size 4 block be 2x2 or 4x1 or 1x4? What for block size 7? In the simplest case you make some block, mark its region as occupied and try to put the next blocks.

Comment: Use a 1 column by Z rows matrix and it becomes trivial. You need to work on defining the problem a bit more.

Comment: I have worked the solution out thanks both Brian and MBo.  I first took  it up to myself to step and look at the logic more thoroughly (Thanks Brian) as that indeed is what had to be done.  Then as MBo suggested, I realized that I needed a validating matrix routine that supplies and fulfills to what I was needing.  Combining both of your input has resulted success.  Thank you guys for shining the light where needed... Cheers!

Comment: A Thank you to everyone for your help in this matter, including you Zeus for your efforts as well kind sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
// x = seGroups.Value (Number of Groups)
// y = seNumsPerGroup.Value (Numbers per Group)
// z = MAX_NUMBERS

// Other components.
// sgNumbers = TStringGrid that is by 8 rows and 10 columns
// chkDoingCombinations = Checkbox that indicates to do combination building.
// chkGenGrouping = Checkbox that indicates we are to group numbers during random generation.

// Please define these types.
TMyCoords = record
  Col: Integer;
  Row: Integer;
end;

TMatrix = TMyCoords;

TMyObject = class(TObject)
  private
    bPaint: Boolean;
  public
    property IsPainted: Boolean read bPaint write bPaint default False;
  end;


// Our Constants
const
  MAX_ROWS: Integer = 8;
  MAX_COLS: Integer = 10;
  MAX_ATTEMPTS = 50;
  MAX_NUMBERS = 80;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;
  CellCoords: TMyCoords;
  iMAX_NUMBERS: Integer;

// Function that determines how a group will be built
// on our given grid matrix.
function TfrmMain.DetermineGroupMatrixType (): TMatrix;
var
  iResult: Integer;
  Matrix: TMatrix;
begin
  Matrix.Col := 0;
  Matrix.Row := 0;
  case seNumPerGroup.Value of
    // Groups of 2
    2: begin
         iResult := Random (2);
         // Are we doing Vertical?
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end; // End of Case 2

    // Groups of 3
    3: begin
         iResult := Random (2);
         // Are we doing Vertical?
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end;  // End of Case 3

    // Groups of 4
    4: begin
         iResult := Random (3);
         // Are we to create a block?
         if iResult = 2 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 2;
           Matrix.Row := 2;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;

         // Are we going Vertically.
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end;  // End of Case 4

    // Groups of 5
    5: begin
         iResult := Random (2);
         // Are we doing Vertical?
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end; // End of Case 5

    // Groups of 6
    6: begin
         iResult := Random (3);
         // Are we to create a block?
         if iResult = 2 then
         begin
           // Yes, now which type of block.
           iResult := Random (2);
           if iResult = 1 then
           begin
             Matrix.Col := 3;
             Matrix.Row := 2;
           end
           else
           begin
             Matrix.Col := 2;
             Matrix.Row := 3;
           end;

           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;

         // Are we going Vertically.
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end;  // End of Case 6

    // Groups of 7
    7: begin
         iResult := Random (2);
         // Are we doing Vertical?
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end;  // End of Case 7

    // Groups of 8
    8: begin
         iResult := Random (3);
         // Are we to create a block?
         if iResult = 2 then
         begin
           // Yes, now which type of block.
           iResult := Random (2);
           if iResult = 1 then
           begin
             Matrix.Col := 4;
             Matrix.Row := 2;
           end
           else
           begin
             Matrix.Col := 2;
             Matrix.Row := 4;
           end;

           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;

         // Are we going Vertically.
         if iResult = 1 then
         begin
           Matrix.Col := 1;
           Matrix.Row := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end
         else
         begin
           // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
           Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
           Matrix.Row := 1;
           Result := Matrix;
           exit;
         end;
       end;  // End of Case 8

    // Groups of 9
    9: begin
         // Yes, now which type of block.
         Matrix.Col := 3;
         Matrix.Row := 3;
         Result := Matrix;
         exit;
       end; // End of Case 9

    // Groups of 10
    10: begin
          iResult := Random (3);
          // Are we to create a block?
          if iResult = 2 then
          begin
            // Yes, now which type of block.
            iResult := Random (2);
            if iResult = 1 then
            begin
              Matrix.Col := 5;
              Matrix.Row := 2;
            end
            else
            begin
              Matrix.Col := 2;
              Matrix.Row := 5;
            end;

            Result := Matrix;
            exit;
          end;

          if iResult = 1 then
          begin
            // Yes, now which type of block.
            Matrix.Col := 10;
            Matrix.Row := 1;
            Result := Matrix;
            exit;
          end;

          // Otherwise, Go Horizontally.
          Matrix.Col := seNumPerGroup.Value;
          Matrix.Row := 1;
          Result := Matrix;
          exit;
        end; // End of Case 10
  end; // End of Case Block.
end;

// Function that calculates on our grid, exact row and col coordinates
function TfrmMain.CalculateGridCoords (CellNumber: Integer): TMyCoords;
begin
  Result.Row := (CellNumber div MAX_COLS);
  if (CellNumber > (MAX_COLS - 1)) and ((CellNumber mod MAX_COLS) = 0) then
     Dec (Result.Row);

  if (CellNumber mod MAX_COLS) = 0 then
     Result.Col := MAX_COLS - 1
  else
     Result.Col := (CellNumber mod MAX_COLS) - 1;
end;

// This function builds the sized group and tests for conflicts
// with existing numbers that have been selected on the grid
function TFrmMain.ValidateGrouping (iStartNumber: Integer; Matrix: TMatrix;
                                    var iSetNumbers: array of Integer): Boolean;
var
  iCol, iRow, iOrigBaseNum: Integer;
  myObj: TMyObject;
  myCoords: TMyCoords;
  iX, iY: Integer;

begin
  // Default Return result.
  Result := False;

  // Iterate through our Column and test if number is used.
  iOrigBaseNum := iStartNumber;
  for iCol := 0 to Matrix.Col - 1 do
  begin
    // First check to see if this is out of range or the number
    // has already been used.
    iX := iStartNumber + iCol;
    if (iX > MAX_NUMBERS) or (iX < 1) or (iSetNumbers[iX] > 0) then
       exit;

    // Iterate throu block row and check every number to
    // ensure none are in use.
    for iRow := 0 to Matrix.Row - 1 do
    begin
      iX := iStartNumber + (iRow * MAX_COLS);
      // Check this number to see if is out of range or the number
      // has already been used.
      if ((iX > MAX_NUMBERS) or (iX < 1)) or (iSetNumbers [iX] > 0) then
         exit;
    end; // End of For iRow
  end; //End of For iCol

  // If we have made it this far, then we are looking good to
  // create our block of numbers.
  iStartNumber := iOrigBaseNum;
  for iCol := 0 to Matrix.Col - 1 do
  begin
    // Calculate next position within block area
    iX := iStartNumber + iCol;

    // Set and Highlight on Grid.
    myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iX);
    myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
    // Mark this cell for Highlighting
    myObj.IsPainted := True;

    // Iterate throu block row and check every number to
    // ensure none are in use.
    iY := iX;
    for iRow := 0 to Matrix.Row - 1 do
    begin
      // Calculate next position within block area
      iX := iY + (iRow * MAX_COLS);

      // Set and Highlight on Grid.
      iSetNumbers [iX] := iX;
      myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iX);
      myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
      // Mark this cell for Highlighting
      myObj.IsPainted := True;
    end; // End of For iRow
  end; //End of For iCol

  Result := True;
end;

// This is the calling procedure to start with group
// or individual number generation
procedure TfrmMain.GenerateRandomNumbers(Sender: TObject);
var
  iNum: Integer;
  iSetNumbers: Array [1 .. MAX_NUMBERS] of Integer;
  iTotalNumbers: Integer;
  iX: Integer;
  myObj: TMyObject;
  myCoords: TMyCoords;

  // Procedure that starts the Random Number Generation process.
  procedure GenerateNumbers (iTotalNumbers: Integer);
  var
    bFound: Boolean;
    iX: Integer;
    myObj: TMyObject;
    iCount: Integer;

    // Function that generates our grouping of numbers.
    function GenerateGroup (var iBaseNum: Integer): Boolean;
    var
      iIndex: Integer;
      Matrix: TMatrix;
      iCount: Integer;

    begin
      // Build all Groups
      for iIndex := 1 to seGroups.Value do
      begin
        Matrix := DetermineGroupMatrixType();
        bFound := True;
        iCount := 1;

        while (bFound) and (iCount < MAX_ATTEMPTS) do
        begin
          if (iBaseNum = 0) or (iSetNumbers [iBaseNum] > 0) then
          begin
            // Invalid, Randomise a number and Initialise
            iBaseNum := Random (iMAX_NUMBERS);
            // Increase the number of attempts.
            Inc (iCount);
            continue;
          end;

          // Next we need to set and build our group of numbers and
          // ensure that each group does not conflict with other
          // numbers.
          bFound := ValidateGrouping (iBaseNum, Matrix, iSetNumbers);
          bFound := bFound xor True;

          // if failed, pick another number.
          if bFound then
          begin
            iBaseNum := Random (iMAX_NUMBERS);
            // Increase the number of attempts.
            Inc (iCount);
          end;
        end; // End of While Loop
      end;

      Result := True;
    end; // End of Function

  begin
    // Are we doing combinations?
    if chkDoingCombinations.Checked then
    begin
      // Generate our number list
      bFound := True;
      iCount := 0;
      while (bFound) and (iCount < MAX_ATTEMPTS) do
      begin
        // Randomise a number and Initialise
        iNum := Random (iMAX_NUMBERS);
        if (iNum = 0) or (iSetNumbers [iNum] > 0) then
        begin
          // Increase our number of attempts
          Inc (iCount);
          continue;
        end;

        // Are we grouping numbers?
        if chkGenGrouping.Checked then
        begin
          // If we group generation failed
          if not GenerateGroup (iNum) then
          begin
            iSetNumbers [iNum] := 0;
            // Increase our number of attempts
            Inc (iCount);
            bFound := True;
            continue;
          end
          else
            // Success :)
            bFound := False;
        end
        else
        begin
          // Record Number
          bFound := False;
          iSetNumbers [iNum] := iNum;

          // Set and Highlight on Grid.
          myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iNum);
          myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
          myObj.bPaint := True;
        end;
      end;

      // Did we exceed all of our attempts?
      if (iCount >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) then
      begin
        // Report Impossibility factor.
        MessageDlg ('The number of attempts have been exceeded and results to / near impossibility!'#13#10#13#10+
                    'Please try again to use different random sets!', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
        exit;
      end;

      exit;
    end; // End of If

    // Otherwise random pick total set of numbers.
    // Generate our number list
    iTotalNumbers := seNumsPerGroup.Value;
    for iX := 1 to iTotalNumbers do
    begin
      bFound := True;
      while bFound do
      begin
        // Randomise a number and Initialise
        iNum := Random (iMAX_NUMBERS);
        if iNum = 0 then
           continue;

        // Checked our saved numbers to see if already picked.
        if (iSetNumbers[iNum] > 0) then
           continue;

        // Record Number
        bFound := False;
        iSetNumbers [iNum] := iNum;

        // Set and Highlight on Grid.
        myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iNum);
        myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
        myObj.bPaint := True;
      end; // End of While Loop
    end;
  end;

begin
  ZeroMemory (@iSetNumbers, sizeof(iSetNumbers));
  // Set all Cells with appropriate numerical ID.
  for iX := 1 to (iMAX_NUMBERS - 1) do
  begin
    // Calculator Position
    myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iX);

    // Set appropriate cell with Numerical ID
    myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
    myObj.bPaint := False;
  end;

  // Are we using combinations?
  if chkDoingCombinations.Checked then
  begin
    // Are we to generate groupings?
    if chkGenGrouping.Checked then
       iTotalNumbers := seGroups.Value
    else
       // No Standard Set Numbers.
       iTotalNumbers := seGroups.Value * seNumPerGroup.Value;

    // Generate our random number list.
    GenerateNumbers (iTotalNumbers);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Keeping it real, max 40 numbers maximum!
    iTotalNumbers := seNumsPerGroup.Value;
    if iTotalNumbers > 40 then
       iTotalNumbers := 40;

    // Generate our random number list.
    GenerateNumbers (iTotalNumbers);
  end;

  // Refresh our grid panel so highlighted numbers show up.
  sgNumbers.Repaint;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Initialise our Matrix grid and assign all possible objects.
  InitialiseGrid;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var
  iX: Integer;
  myObj: TMyObject;
  myCoords: TMyCoords;
begin
  // Set all Cells with appropriate numerical ID.
  for iX := 1 to MAX_NUMBERS do
  begin
    try
      // Calculator Position
      myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iX);

      // Set appropriate cell with Numerical ID
      myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row]);
      // Release CELL MyObject
      FreeAndNil (myObj);
    except
      continue;
    end;
  end;
end;


// Initialise String Grid to contain the Grid Matrix
procedure TfrmMain.InitialiseGrid;
var
  iX: Integer;
  myObj: TMyObject;
  myCoords: TMyCoords;

begin
  try
    // Set all Cells with appropriate numerical ID and object.
    for iX := 1 to MAX_NUMBERS do
    begin
      // Calculator Position
      myCoords := CalculateGridCoords (iX);

      // Set appropriate cell with Numerical ID
      sgNumbers.Cells[myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row] := IntToStr (iX);
      myObj := TMyObject.Create;
      // Mark this cell for NON Highlighting
      myObj.IsPainted := False;
      // Set Cell Assigned Object
      sgNumbers.Objects [myCoords.Col, myCoords.Row] := TObject (myObj);
    end;

  except
    // Termination application if Exception occurs.
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.sgNumbersDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  myObj: TMyObject;
begin
  bIsPainting := True;
  with TStringGrid (Sender) do
  begin
    myObj := TMyObject (sgNumbers.Objects [ACol, ARow]);
    if myObj = nil then
       exit;

    // Is this cell marked for Highlighting?
    if myObj.IsPainted then
    begin
      //paint the background clActiveBorder
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clActiveBorder;
      Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
      DrawText (Canvas.Handle, PChar(Cells[ACol, ARow]), Length(Cells[ACol, ARow]),
                Rect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);

    end
    else
    begin
      //paint the background clGrayText
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clGrayText;
      Canvas.FillRect (Rect);
      DrawText (Canvas.Handle, PChar(Cells[ACol, ARow]), Length(Cells[ACol, ARow]),
                Rect, DT_WORDBREAK or DT_EXPANDTABS or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
    end;
  end;

  bIsPainting := False;
end;
```